# Is there a way I can specify conditional defines when using a package?

Tags: c#, nuget

I have a package `Fluxor.Web.Blazor.ReduxDevTools` which allows the user to specify whether they use `System.Text.Json` or `Newtonsoft.Json` for serialization.

But this means I must have a dependency on both, which is a problem because this is a Blazor library and it increases the payload size.

Is there a way I can compile my package so the consumer can define either `Fluxor_NewtonsoftJson` or `Fluxor_SystemTextJson` and when they compile they will somehow have a different build that has different dependencies?

Comment: Create 2 packages?

Comment: You want for user to define which one of your two packages to use with some marker? Or you want to somehow achieve that with 1 package?

Comment: I want one package which uses STJ by default,  or NSJ if the consumer defines FLUXOR_USENEWTONSOFTJSON. I've seen this done before,  I just don't recall where.

Comment: I doubt it's possible with one package (without it referencing both system.text and newtonsoft of course). However it should be possible with two separate packages, and then conditionally use one or another based on define. That is consumer of your package might even be not aware that two packages exist.